# Classic asp: why doesn't Request.QueryString("foo").toString() work in a javascript (JScript) based page?

Tags: post, asp-classic

All I want to do is

- Get the name-value pairs that were supplied to Request.QueryString
- Populate a javascript object (aka hash) with keys from the names and values from the values
- Halt the page if one of the expected hash values is the empty string

The Request.QueryString object is reminding me why I hated classic asp even before it was an abandoned technology. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querystring contents are treated as string by default i believe..

But if you have to, you can always do `String( request.querystring("foo") );`

Are the keys known before-hand ? or you want to iterate through the pairs and retrieve both key and value ?

Comment: Fortunately the keys are known ahead of time. The real problem is the API for Request.QueryString. I resorted to if( Request.QueryString(foo).count == 0) to detect if the "foo" parameter is missing. I still do not know if String() will work since this is javascript-based asp. Thanks a lot for the feedback though. The default String makes sense, but then  I wonder why toString() method still does not work. (Not a priority tho, I just want to get the thing finished.)

Answer (score 2):

The Request.QueryString collection has an awkward interface, particularly when it comes to iterating or cases where there are multiple params with the same name. I suggest grabbing the whole querystring using Request.QueryString.Item() or Request.ServerVariables('QUERY_STRING') and parse it using unescape/decodeURIComponent. It's a bit of effort, but gives you more control and consistency.

A simple example that lowercases keys:

```
var params = parseQueryString(Request.QueryString.Item());

function parseQueryString(qs) {
  var parsed = {}, pairs = qs.split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i ++) {
    var pair = pairs[i], pos = pair.indexOf('=');
    if (pos < 0) pos = pair.length;
    parsed[unescape(pair.slice(0, pos)).toLowerCase()] = unescape(pair.slice(pos + 1));
  }
  return parsed;
}
```